# Trying to pull data from params object in Rails API using JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

With Rspec, I am trying to build a spec testing some basic http requests.  I'm making a rookie mistake somewhere and need help finding it.

I am purposely making the spec fail with a nonsense expectation so the error message will tell me what I'm getting -- once I figure things out I'll correct the expectation:

```
  user = create(:member)
  json_data = {email: user.email, password: user.password}.to_json
  post "api/v1/users/sign_in", json_data, format: :json
  expect(last_response.body).to eq "foobar"
```

api/v1/users/sign_in routes to the following controller:

```
class API::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json
  def create
    render text: params
  end
end
```

This gives the error:

> expected: "foobar"
>               got: "{\"{\\"email\\":\\"7abdiel_roob@smithrau.biz\\",\\"password\\":\\"12345678\\"}\"=>nil,
>   \"action\"=>\"create\", \"controller\"=>\"api/v1/sessions\"}"

Ok great. My data is getting to the server and the server sends it back, which is what I want.  In my next step I try to grab the email.  I change the controller to

```
class API::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   respond_to :json
   def create
      render text: params[:email]
    end
 end
```

and I get

> expected: "foobar"
>               got: " "

I looks to me that the params hash is using the JSOn data I sent in the request as the name of a key, not actually a value.  Or maybe this is a strong_params thing? I've tried many things and can't seem to pull the data I want out of the params object.

Comment: The probleme here is that you are trying to access JSON object as if it were normal params , i would suggest you decode the params and then access whatever your email nomally

Comment: @Kiloreux, Rails will automatically decode the body of a JSON format request into the params hash. You should not try to decode it yourself - you are just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that you are double encoding the JSON data which you are sending in your spec.

```
json_data = {email: user.email, password: user.password}
post "api/v1/users/sign_in", json_data, format: :json
```

RSpec will automatically encode the request body as JSON for you.

Comment: That did it, thank you.  How do I set this as the answer?

Comment: Click the check right under the vote up/down buttons